# Display table or chart in the same box upon clicking different buttons in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, action-button

I am trying to create an app with 2 buttons to show either chart or table (not both) in the same box content.
For example, if user click on chart button, chart appears. similarly clicking on table button, table appear in the same place and chart disappears.

minimal example

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  shinyApp(
    ui = shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
      header = dashboardHeader(),
      sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
      body = dashboardBody(
        actionButton(inputId = 'input1', label = 'Chart'),
        actionButton(inputId = 'input2', label = 'Table'),
        box(
          uiOutput('plot_table_output'))
      ),
      title = "DashboardPage"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$plot_table_output <- renderUI({
        if(input$input1 >0) {
          plotOutput('my_plot')
        }
        if(input$input2 >0) {
          dataTableOutput('mytable')
        } 
      })
      
      output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
        mydf <- data.frame(X=1:10, Y=1:10)
        plot(mydf$X, mydf$Y, type = 'l')
      })
      
      output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
        mydf <-  data.frame(X=1:10, Y=1:10)
        mydf
      })   
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `ObserveEvent()`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      actionButton(inputId = 'input1', label = 'Chart'),
      actionButton(inputId = 'input2', label = 'Table'),
      box(
        uiOutput('plot_table_output'))
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$input1, {
      output$plot_table_output <- renderUI({
          plotOutput('my_plot')
      })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$input2, {
      output$plot_table_output <- renderUI({
        dataTableOutput('mytable')
      })
    })
    
    output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
      mydf <- data.frame(X=1:10, Y=1:10)
      plot(mydf$X, mydf$Y, type = 'l')
    })
    
    output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
      mydf <-  data.frame(X=1:10, Y=1:10)
      mydf
    })   
  }
)
```